# CardView is not working in api 22 and below in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

CardView is not working in api 22 and below. It's showing blank, but in Android 6 and above, it's working fine. I have used weights for row and columns, and I think it is not supported in Android 5.1 and below. Give any alternative for this.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:rowCount="3">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#660000"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/About"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="7dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/aboutaul" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: android:elevation requires you to have at least api >=21

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Removing the 'app:cardCornerRadius="n"' fixed the CardView going blank for me.

It seems there is no limit for the radius on api22 and lower, so it can end up covering the entire CardView, if too high.

Just figured this out, so I have had no time to try working out rounded corners without this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line in cardView

```
android:elevation="6dp"
```

Use this

```
app:cardElevation="6dp"
```

Comment: I have one other question.
elevetaion has a prefix "android"
cardElevation has a prefix "app" 
What's the difference in those?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos it's a different namespace. IIRC `app` makes it use the appcompat definitions rather than the API-dependent ones.

Comment: android namespace is reserved for framework related properties. for all other you can use anything else. `app` is by convension. you can also use `foobar` instead of `app`

Comment: actually its not working can you give any other answer